# How to change position from absolute to relative in charts in CanvasJS

Tags: javascript, html, css, position, canvasjs

I need to convert default position of two charts in CanvasJS from absolute to relative. From inspect elements of the browser I saw that it could be changed. Then I tried to change the position of the `div` to relative as follows but it didn't changed the position of the chart.

```
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 d-flex flex-column" style="background-color: ghostwhite;">
    <div id="barChartContainer1" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;  padding: 10px;  display: block; position: relative;"></div>
    <div id="barChartContainer2" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;  padding: 10px;  display: block; position: relative;"></div>
    <div id="barChartContainer3" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;  padding: 10px;  display: block; position: relative;"></div>
</div>
```

three charts overlaps on each other. I tried by changing java script as follows but it didn't do the work I expected.

```
var chart1 = new CanvasJS.Chart("barChartContainer2", {
  animationEnabled: true,
  position: "relative",
  height: 600,
})
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 1):

This css rule works for me:

`.canvasjs-chart-container>canvas:first-of-type { position: relative !important; }`

Answer (score 0):

You can try implementing [Flexbox](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/) design in CSS3:

```css
#container{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div id="container">
  <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;  padding: 10px; background-color: red;"></div>
  <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;  padding: 10px; background-color: blue;"></div>
  <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;  padding: 10px; background-color: green;"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

If that does not work, this will for sure:

```js
var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chart1",
    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Chart 1"
        },
        axisX: {
            interval: 10,
        },
        data: [
        {
            type: "splineArea",
            color: "rgba(255,12,32,.3)",
            dataPoints: [
                { x: 1, y: 10 },
                { x: 2, y: 30 },
            ]
        },
        ]
    });
chart.render();

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chart2",
    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Chart 2"
        },
        axisX: {
            interval: 10,
        },
        data: [
        {
            type: "splineArea",
            color: "rgba(32,255,12,.3)",
            dataPoints: [
                { x: 1, y: 10 },
                { x: 2, y: 20 },
            ]
        },
        ]
    });
chart.render();

var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chart3",
    {
        animationEnabled: true,
        title: {
            text: "Chart 3"
        },
        axisX: {
            interval: 10,
        },
        data: [
        {
            type: "splineArea",
            color: "rgba(12,32,255,.3)",
            dataPoints: [
                { x: 1, y: 30 },
                { x: 2, y: 1 },
            ]
        },
        ]
    });
chart.render();
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>
<div id="chart1" style="height: 100%; width: 30%;  display: inline-block;">   </div>
<div id="chart2" style="height: 100%; width: 30%;  display: inline-block;"></div>
<div id="chart3" style="height: 100%; width: 30%;  display: inline-block;">
</div>
```

Comment: Not working, I think adding CSS to div elements doesn't affect the default chart settings. Is there is a way to apply it in the java script code.

Comment: Edited my answer accordingly @SjAnupa